# Clump raster values depending on class attribute

Tags: r, raster

I have a raster values (Raster package):

```
values(r)<-c(2,1,0,0,1,
             1,1,1,0,0,
             1,0,1,0,0,
             2,1,0,1,0,
             2,2,0,0,2)
```

and I would like to **find the clumps = patches in each class** (values 1,2). Unfortunately the clump(Raster) function return patches separated by O or NA value so it mixes values 1,2 into single patch.

Also, I would like to **exclude patches containg only 1 pixel** and make them NA,  which is possible with

```
values(rc)[!duplicated(values(rc)) & !duplicated(values(rc),fromLast=T)] <- NA
#(many thanks to @agstudy)
```

However, I would like to exclude patches containing only 1 pixel but **separated by class value** (1,2).

Finally, I would like to obtain:

```
values(r)<-c(NA,1,NA,NA,NA,
             1,1,1,NA,NA,
             1,NA,1,NA,NA,
             2,NA,NA,1,NA,
             2,2,NA,NA,NA)
```

Code exemple:

```
library("raster")
r <- raster(ncols=5, nrows=5)
values(r)<-c(2,1,0,0,1,
             1,1,1,0,0,
             1,0,1,0,0,
             2,1,0,1,0,
             2,2,0,0,2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably too late, but I found this question unanswered while working on the same topic.

The answer is to loop through all the class values and do the clumping for each class separately while filling a new raster with NA's where the clumps have a frequency of 1 (original code for removing small clumps: https://geoscripting-wur.github.io/AdvancedRasterAnalysis/#Applying_a_raster_sieve_by_clumping). By multiplying this NA-raster with the original, the 1 pixel patches are removed.

Note that we have to expand the raster, otherwise the left and right edges are 'touching' since the default x-coordinates are from -180 to 180. At the end the final raster is cropped to its original extent.

```
# extend raster, otherwise left and right edges are 'touching'
r <- extend(r, c(1,1))

# get al unique class values in the raster
clVal <- unique(r)

# remove '0' (background)
clVal <- clVal[!clVal==0]

# create a 1-value raster, to be filled in with NA's
r.NA <- setValues(raster(r), 1)

  # set background values to NA
  r.NA[r==0]<- NA

# loop over all unique class values
for (i in clVal) {

  # create & fill in class raster
  r.class <- setValues(raster(r), NA)
  r.class[r == i]<- 1

  # clump class raster
  clp <- clump(r.class)

  # calculate frequency of each clump/patch
  cl.freq <- as.data.frame(freq(clp))

  # store clump ID's with frequency 1
  rmID <- cl.freq$value[which(cl.freq$count == 1)]

  # assign NA to all clumps whose ID's have frequency 1
  r.NA[clp %in% rmID] <- NA
} 

# multiply original raster by the NA raster
r <- r * r.NA

# crop the originally extended raster ((row 2-6 and column 2-6))
r <- crop(r, extent(r, 2, 6, 2, 6 ))

getValues(r)
#  [1] NA  1 NA NA NA
#       1  1  1 NA NA  
#       1 NA  1 NA NA  
#       2  1 NA  1 NA  
#       2  2 NA NA NA
```